# Polymer 1.0+ iron-image - best practice to wait for existence of image file to avoid 404 error

Tags: javascript, image, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'd like to know what the best practice would be in polymer 1.0+, using iron-image to load a file that is generated by another backend asynchronous process.  I would like iron-image to wait for the backend process to finish creating image file, and show the placeholder image until it can be loaded.  Currently, I intermittently receive a 404 error when the backend process is still working to generate the image.

In the past, I would've executed something like the below js function in a timer interval...but I believe there must be a better approach, and one that isn't deprecated (Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience).

```
imageExists: function(image_url) {
     var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

     http.open('HEAD', image_url, false);
     http.send();

     return http.status != 404;
},
```

Is there something built-in to iron-image capabilities that I'm not taking advantage of to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `placeholder` attribute:

```
/**
 * This image will be used as a background/placeholder until the src image has
 * loaded.  Use of a data-URI for placeholder is encouraged for instant rendering.
 */
placeholder: {
  type: String,
  value: null,
  observer: '_placeholderChanged'
},
```

Sample:

```
<iron-image style="width:400px; height:400px;" placeholder="./loading.png"
      sizing="cover" preload src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400"></iron-image>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily accomplish this with the addition of iron-ajax. Use iron-ajax to handle the request for the image, meanwhile pass or explicitly define your placeholder image in your component (as I have in my example). On success you then inject the new image into the component.

https://jsfiddle.net/devappended2/hwrg1sdu/

```html
<dom-module id="my-component">
    <template>
     <iron-ajax
      auto
            url="{{url}}"
            on-response="_imageResponse"
        </iron-ajax>
        <iron-image sizing="contain" preload fade src="{{image}}"></iron-image>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
Polymer({
    is: 'my-component',
    properties: {
        image: {
         type:   String,
         value:   'path/placeholder.jpg'
        }
    },
    _imageResponse: function(e, detail){
     this.image = detail;
    }
});
</script>
```